# Which of the following groups show +M and -I effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

> Which of the following group show *+M* and *-I* effect?
>
> (**A**) $\ce{-\underset{\underset{\huge O}{||}}{C}-F}$
> (**B**) $\ce{-\underset{\underset{\huge O}{||}}{C}-OR}$
> (**C**) $\ce{-O^-}$
> (**D**) $\ce{-OH}$

Answer is option **D**. **D** is obviously correct, but why not option **C**? $\ce{-O^-}$ has electrons to donate and is electronegative.

Comment: O- is an electron-rich species, which donates its charge to the ring, stringly activating it. It has a very strong +I effect!